# How to model data using CoreData and PyList?

Tags: ios, core-data

The app I am working on is supposed to calculate amount of salts that need to be used to compose solutions with given concentrations. The model is included in attached github link:

https://github.com/zenekbarburka/buffersModel/blob/master/eforeCoreData

in summary: there are 3 classes:

1. Salt: name, molWeight, subscriptedCharacters properties are constant for a given instance, property attributedName is calculated based on salt.name and salt. subscriptedCharacters
2. Ingredient: properties type, concentration, multiplier, percentage are input by user
            property amount is calculated based on ingredient.type ingredient.concentration
           ingredient.multiplier. ingredient.percentage and buffer.volume using method 
            calculateConcentrations in Buffer class once all the Ingredients are in the array
3. Buffer: properties name, volume are input by user when initializing, ingredients is initialized as an     empty array and elements are input by user later on. 
     This class also contains a method calculateConcentrations, which calculates amounts for     each ingredient.

The model is working fine and calculates amounts. I am at the point where I would like to enable storing of data between runs.

I am considering using `CoreData` and `PyList` the following approach:

```
Entity: Buffer
attributes:  name, volume, favorite

Entity: Ingredient
attributes: concentration, multiplier, percentage
```

Having entity Buffer and Ingredients I would like to create a Buffer class instance

The problem is not knowing how to include Ingredients array so that every ingredient has a type property type of Salt.

Since properties of Salt won’t be changing and there will be a lot (around 100) of instances of this class I would like to have a `PyList` for them.

I am thinking the way to go could be adding a name attribute to Ingredient entity, and based on this the correct salt would be picked from `PyList` (members could go as enum).

So in the end I would like to have a following flow

[flow-edited](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLBYV.png)

Is this the reasonable way to go?

This is my very first attempt to model anything using `CoreData` so I am a bit overwhelmed. I would really appreciate some input, including recommendations for tutorials that deal with modeling. What I found so far is either pretty basic or too advanced. Thank you in advance

Comment: Since Python isn't available in iOS apps, I'm not sure how you would use PyList in an app.

Comment: @TomHarrington , sorry, what I meant is a property list, plist. I actually managed to implement it so that the only issue I have now is putting Ingredients array into Buffer entity